# Python if statement skipping code even though condition is met

Tags: python-2.7, if-statement

I am trying to check if an entry is already in the database and add the entry if it isn't but the if statement never runs even though the condition is met.

```
        userCurs.execute("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM images WHERE imageLink=?)", (image,))
        exists = userCurs.fetchone()
        if exists is None:
            addImage(userName,image,'','')
        else:
            print '--------> image skipped'
            print userCurs.fetchone()
```

I get this output:

```
--------> image skipped
None
--------> image skipped
None
```

and no entries are made to the database

Comment: You're calling `fetchone` twice. Could that be an issue?

Comment: when I change it to exists I get 
`--------> image skipped
(0,)
--------> image skipped
(0,)`

Comment: You are calling `fetchOne` twice, what if you `print exists` on the last line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SQL statement:

```
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM images WHERE imageLink=?)
```

will always return a single row.  The value of the column in that row will be the result of the `EXISTS()` function, which will be TRUE if any matches are found, or FALSE otherwise.

Since your original code only tested for the existence of a row in the result, and the full statement will always return exactly one row, you get the behavior you see.

What I think you should do is have your query return a rowset that has zero rows if no matches are found, and one (or more) rows if matches are found:

```
userCurs.execute("SELECT 1 FROM images WHERE imageLink=?", (image,))
```

Now your original test should work - if no imageLinks match the query, then there will be no rows in the result, so the first `fetchone()` will return a null object as you expect.

Of course, as several others have mentioned, you should ony call `fetchone()` once per row since it moves the cursor.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by changing the code to

```
        userCurs.execute("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM images WHERE imageLink=?)", (image,))
        exists = userCurs.fetchone()
        if exists[0] == 0:
            addImage(userName,image,'','')
        else:
            print '--------> image skipped'
            print exists
```

As people have said the calling fetchone() twice gives different results the actual value of exists was (0,)

Comment: Ah, yes, the row will return 0 or 1. Use `not exists[0]` then.

Answer (score 0):

Don't call `cursor.fetchone()` again; the *next* row is *always* empty. Reuse the variable. You are fetching a `(0,)` or `(1,)` tuple; you could use tuple assignment to extract the flag value (note the comma on `exits, =`):

```
exists, = userCurs.fetchone()
if not exists:
    addImage(userName, image, '', '')
else:
    print '--------> image skipped'
    print exists
```

Now `exists` will be set to `0` or `1`, rather than `(0,)` or `(1,)` and the `if not exists:` test will not pass for the `0` case.

Comment: I think it is because, the not exists case won't execute ever. Since the query always returns one row, it never gets added in the database.

Comment: It's not the case that "the `not exists` case won't execute ever" - note that `exists` in this code is the first member of the tuple returned by `fetchone()`, not the tuple itself (it referenced the tuple in the original code).  This is clarified by the last sentence - you can try it out to verify if you have a `pyodbc` setup to hand.